# Does square integrable fourier transform mean the original function square integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform

if $f\in L^1(R^n)$ and its Fourier transform $\hat{f}=\int f(x) e^{-ixt} \ dx \in L^2(R^n)$, then can we show $f \in L^2(R^n)$?

If yes, can you tell me why?  If not, can you give me some counterexamples? I also see some obscure answers elsewhere with some high-order mathematcical concepts such as fourier transform in schwardz space, I can't understand it. If yes, can you prove it with the knowledge within the scope of Rudin's 'Real and Complex Analysis'?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is a little different from Plancherel theorem. If we use the Plancherel theorem, take the L2-inverse fourier transform of $\hat{f}$, we get a $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{f})=h\in L^2$, now the problem is why $f=h$ a.e.? Do you get my meaning here?